# Android FlexboxLayout : android:animateLayoutChanges not working when child view resized

Tags: android, flexbox, android-animation, android-flexboxlayout

I added this option to my [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) for had animation when children move :

`android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

Unfortunately child view are animated only when I add child, but not when one child is resized!
Have you got any idea to always have an animation?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To animate children when they change their size you need to enable CHANGING transition type of the container's layoutTransition:

```
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = new LayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
parentView.setLayoutTransition(layoutTransition);
```

[LayoutTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition)